# CSS full page background height of scrollable div

Tags: css, scrollable

there is html code:

```
 <div class="container content">
 <div class="wrap-container row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 text-center text-white left">
     <h2 class="mt-5">Contact</h2>
      <h1> 987 123 456</h1>  
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ml-auto right">
     <div class="form">
        <form>
          <!-- form controls -->
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>       
 </div>
</div>
```

now in css

```
.content.container {
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
.left {
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #808080, 2px 2px 1px rgba(47,171,81, 0.8);
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;


}
.right {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #b9b9b9;
    margin: 2rem;
    height: 86%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form {
    overflow: auto;
    height:99%;
    padding-right: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 110%;
    left: 0;
    right: -2rem;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .content.container {
        height: 200vh;
        display: block;
    }

    .wrap-container {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        overflow: auto;

    }
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .right, .left {
        margin:0;
    }
    .right {
        height: auto;
    }
    .form {
        padding-right: 1.5rem;
        /*height: auto;*/
        display: block;
    }
 }
```

now, when .form div is getting higher than verticah height (100vh) content is cut. In small devices like phone I can scroll .form div content but only vh is visible, there is no visible submit button :/
I added in media query height 200vh of .content.container what solved problem but I think it's not proper way.

How should I extend scrollable div till its content height?

Comment: add jsfiddle of it

Answer (score 0):

Children adapting to parents height is best resolved using flexbox.

I have set the wrap-container as flex and flex-direction:column as the children are stacked. I would try to avoid setting different heights to all children.

Then just add overflow-y:scroll to the form.

```
.wrap-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.form {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you want to achive something like: 100vh for the main container and items in overflow:hidden but .form scrollable, for all devices, it should be done like this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5b7jc77/4/)

Comment: but there still is `height: 200vh` in `.content.container` in media-query `@media (max-width: 768px)`. If you remove this static height div.form is cut.

Comment: So I suppose you want to achive something like: 100vh for the main container and items in overflow:hidden but .form scrollable, for all devices? I have updated the fiddle then.

Comment: This ruined my whole layout :/ I need two columns in media where width is grater than 768px, below this width a need one column. In >768px works well, form is exdended till its content, but <768px is cut

Comment: Problem solved, in media query <768px I've changed from `height: 200vh` to `100%` of `.content.container`